# Coding on the TI-84 calculator

Tags: command-line, calculator, command-prompt, copy-paste, quadratic

ti 84 plus ce command line copy/paste and/or store a line for later use. I'm attempting to create a Program for a Quadratic equation and asking if there is a quicker way to copy a line and paste it under in the next line on the command line. (See photos for example):
[I want to copy/paste this line for next line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEaA8.jpg)--[Like this: (I manually changed to minus sign before the radical sign)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLXBg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can download a desktop app and then plug in your ti 84 plus. This IDE allows for much easier programming than using the calculator itself. This is a link to a youtube video I watched to setup my IDE.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5q1e1IUWdM

Answer (score 0):

I see someone recommended a desktop app, if you download an updated OS (I use version 5.3.1.0058 so I can still use the assembly feature) there is a built in copy/paste.